# Git workflow for multiple feature branch

Tags: github, git-stash

Our current stash repository has a Master and Develop branch.
Anytime if a developer is working on a story a developer creates a branch and once the coding is done a pull request is raised to merge to develop.

So far it has been good but when two developers are working on different feature branches on a  same Repository if a developer merges his changes to develop and other one is still working on, there are issues like merge conflicts and we don't want the two different feature branches to be released together.

I know this is not an issue but we want to avoid release multiple feature branches at a time.

Any thoughts on this on what are the best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to create tags after you have merge to "develop" branch. There is no harm if you wish to release code from "master" branch using tags as well.
Honestly speaking there aren't any hard lines drawn on how you wish to release your code from Git hosted repos?

You may like to follow this sequence

## rebase the feature brnach of second dev from develop branch to get changes of dev1 and avoid merge conflicts

git checkout feature_branch2

git rebase develop

## merge feature-branch2 to develop branch

git checkout develop

git merge feature_branch2

## tag the version you wish to release

git checkout provide_version_you_wish_to_release

git tag tag_name

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is that the 2nd developer should first rebase his feature branch from "develop" branch and then merge his changes back to "develop" branch by creating a pull request.

If you don't wish to release changes from two feature branches simultaneously, you can create tags on the "develop" branch after a merge is successful and release code using these tags.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the second option to release based on tags sounds good to me, should I create a tag after merging to develop or at the branch itself.  We also have a master branch, Does even the master branch have to go with tags ? Can you share some references on how to create tags after merging to develop branch,   I could not find much in google.